# calculating proximity/distance of multiple locations.?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geolocation, location

//windows phone 7 c#//

Scenario:
User is within 20-30 foot if one of **many** locations(which gt updated).

- How do i calculate distance/proximity of multiple locations to the user location(efficiently) as **i want the app to do stuff if the user id within 20-30 foot** of a location(though the app will have to check them all).

any help or advice is welcome thanks.

(*note i will be receiving updates(via azure service) on the locations as they will change.
i include this information as it may relate to ideas about efficiency)

Comment: Is it a dejavu, or I already read a week very similiar question?

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked yesterday?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732660/how-do-i-calculate-distance-proximity-between-one-location-and-another-c

Answer (score 1):

The answer is highly subjective because you haven't really defined what you've already attempted, how efficient it really needs to be, or what kind of data you're working with.

I assume you're using Latitude/Longitude. If that is the case, is there a problem using a simple Lat/Long distance calculation? See here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I can't imagine that would be very inefficient unless you were doing it on the server constantly for many, many users.